# Distributing uniformly N values into P classes

Tags: probability, range

I'll try to briefly explain my need.

I have `N` values and `P` classes. I need to calculate the boundaries for each class such that all the elements will be uniformly distributed over the classes (each class will have to have the same number of elements than another one).

Let `v_1, v_2, ..., v_n` be the list of values, and `MAX` and `MIN` respectively the maximum and minimun values. So, a sample final result should be something like:

```
[MIN,inf_1]
[inf_1,inf_2]
[inf_2,inf_3]
...
[inf_p-1,MAX]
```

where these `P` ranges (classes) are calculated such that the same number of elements (about `N/P`) falls in each of them.

Anyone could suggest me an algorithm/pseudocode?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm  Yes, that's not a mistake: your question is equivalent to drawing a discrete representation of a line segment.  That's because a plot of the bin number against the ranks of the data, when discretized, gives the full answer and any answer is equivalent to a plot that is approximately linear.

Comment: you need [quantiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) here

Comment: @Antoine There's a subtle difference: all quantile algorithms produce approximate answers, but none necessarily produces the ideal answer in general.

Comment: @whuber, I would agree with Antoine and use quantiles. If this is not a good idea, could you please elaborate the application of Bresenham's line algorithm in this case? (and why we should chose the seemingly much more complicated way)